Multiple JWT URI's - Custom JWT Authentication [MongoDB Atlas]
I’ve been using Custom JWT authentication with a google tokenId, and it worked just fine so far. However I also need to add one more authentication provider (Firebase/Github). And when I fetch that tokenId and try to sign in, I get this error:

[Service][AuthError(4346)] failed to lookup key for
kid=2d9b4e69e32b7615d4cd7cafb8fc9b3f81a41ac0. Server log entry: App
Services

I think it might be connected with JWK URI. However since I’m using it for google tokenId at the first place I’ve specified that value as: “https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs”.
And I cannot add multiple JWK URI’s. How can I fix that and support Firebase/Github tokenId at the same time, with Custom JWT auth in MongoDB Atlas?
